# Can I add an item to the Visual Studio 2019 'add-item' quick menu?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, blazor

When working with Blazor, I prefer to keep my code and the html separate. I know this can be done by making a `.razor` and `.razor.cs` file. I found an item template online that allows you to generate both of these files immediately and made some additions to fit my needs.

This works perfectly and shows up in the 'Add New Item' menu: [image]

However, I would like to add it to the items showing directly under add, so I can add components even quicker. So in this list:
[image]

Can custom user templates be added to this quick menu?

Comment: "Quicker" would be to use hotkeys, try ctrl+shift+A in solution explorer.

Comment: I really need to learn more hotkeys, but this one is definitely amazing. Thanks! I'll keep the question open though as I am interested in if it's at all possible.

Comment: @Nijenhof can you share that item template ?

Comment: Here's the repo: https://github.com/nijenhof/blazor-codebehind-template. Though again, I got most of it from someone else I just don't exactly know where anymore. I can also recommend reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-item-templates?view=vs-2019 if you want to know more.

Comment: found this one that add also css file : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chenxu.blazor-component-item-template

Comment: In Options => Environment => Preview Features => Enable experimental Razor editor. 
Then after a restart of VS you can click on the light bulb that appears when you hover over `@code` and select "Extract block to code behind"